# WebSocket not sending data

Tags: javascript, websocket

I've got a bit of a problem with my websocket code intermittently not sending data... As it stands I've written a small C# server which handles the websocket and prints a label.

When running the code on my computer it works fine every time but when I tried it on two other computers I had problems.

I set up some packet sniffing software and what I seem to see as follows:

When the application works... The browser creates a connection to the server which completes the hand shake. Once completed the websocket.onopen event fires. During this event I send data to the server (which I can see in Network Monitor) and then check for buffered data before closing the websocket.

When the application doesn't work... Exactly the same thing happens, however I can't see the data in Network Monitor. The handshake is there, and the onopen event fires and closes the connection but no data is sent over the network...

I installed Network Monitor on both the client and server machine and neither machine can see the missing the data.

Can anyone see any problems in my code below? Failing that does anyone know if this is a bug?

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
var _socket;
function sendXmlToLabelPrinter(strXML)
{
if (_socket == null)
{
console.log("creating socket");
_socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:50/"); // LOCAL
_socket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";

_socket.onopen = function()
{
    console.log("socket opened");

    if (_socket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN)
    {
        try
        {
            _socket.send(strXML);
        }
        catch (ex)
        {
            console.log("an error occured when sending");
            console.log(ex);
        }

        var intClose = setInterval
        ( 
            function()
            {
                console.log("checking socket buffer");
                if (_socket.bufferedAmount == 0)
                {
                    console.log("closing socket");
                    _socket.close();
                    _socket = null;
                    clearTimeout(intClose);
                }
            },
            250
        );
        hideUserMessage();
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("socket not ready");    
    }
};

_socket.onerror = function(myErr)
{
    console.log("error connecting to label printer, set timer to try again");
    _socket.close();
    _socket = null;

    showUserMessage("Error: Please check label printer is running (Retrying in 5s)");
    setTimeout(function(){hideUserMessage()}, 2000);
    setTimeout(function(){sendXmlToLabelPrinter(strXML)}, 5000);
};
}
else
{
    console.log("socket is in use, set timer to retry");
    setTimeout(function(){sendXmlToLabelPrinter(strXML)}, 250);
}
```

}

Comment: On your two other computers are you changing the websocket URL to point to the C# server's address? 127.0.0.1 is localhost, you should look at what your server's actual IP address is and use that address in your script instead.

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for the suggestions. The IP address is as intended. The web application prints to a local printer via the mini server application i wrote. I've tried running the application both using local host and across computers (as network monitor can't sniff local packets) and the issue remains... It could be a network issue somewhere inside of windows but it's not caused by the IP address Im using. Cheers

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your set up then! Is there one computer running the C# server and all other computers trying to connect to that? Or is there a c# server running on each machine?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. There's one C# server running on each computer. The websocket connects back to the server on 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to make sure the TrendMicro or other virus scanners are not interrupting the WebSocket network traffic.  This exact behavior (no packets after handshake) kept a couple of engineers awake at night a couple of years ago with WebSockets on Windows.

Comment: Thanks Nowucca... I didn't look at the AV but didn't notice any issues... I didn't actually try switching it off though. Given that my computer has the AV switched off it's plausible this could be the issue... Although, it seems odd that the problem would be so intermitent if it was the AV or Firewall stopping it... I'll update ASAP though. Cheers.

Comment: Hi, Just to confirm Nowucca had the correct answer. The Sophos Web Intelligence service appears to intermittently stop WebSockets from wokring. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to mark this Nowucca's reply as an answer. Cheers.

Comment: I am so happy that the pain we went through is now embodied here for others to find.  Happy to help!

Comment: I am facing the same issues from few browsers. What is happening handshake happening successfully but browser is not sending any data.I have taken tcp trace  through wireshark where i am not getting any data sent from browser after socket.onopen() event fired. But this situation is not happening always sometimes working immediately, sometimes browsers sending data after 3 or 4 minutes and sometimes not sending any data. i am confused with this peculiar problem. do you think this may happen only for anti virus or other firewall software?if it happens by security software is there any way

Comment: is there any way to bypass it by wss(ssl) or other way

Comment: I had the same problem: I wasn't able to send any data from the client to the server. The cause was the Sophos Web Intelligence. I managed to get a workaround: After connecting I send around 20 dummy messages to the server and finally the Sophos Service forwards the data. Maybe this works for other Virus Scanners too, simply make a for-loop with 20 iterations sending "Test" to the server.

Answer (score 0):

A guess: This is a networking issue, and has to do with the address you're using for your websocket.

Your Websocket URL is pointing to 127.0.0.1, (ie. localhost), which might explain why it works on the computer that is running the server.

```
_socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:50/");
```

Should be changed to:

```
_socket = new WebSocket("ws://yourServer'sPublicIP:50/");
```

You might need a network utility to identify what your server's IP is on the network.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As Nowucca suggested the anti virus software was the culprit. Sophos Web Intelligence intermittently stops Chrome from being able to send data over a websocket. Chrome unfortunately can't detect this and thinks that the data has actually been sent. I confirmed this my trying repeatedly with the service on and off on multiple computers. Hope this helps someone in the future. Cheers.

Comment: So you should give nowucca credit. Select his answer as the right one, and vote for his answer!

Comment: I don't think I can up vote his answer, it says my reputation has to be 15 to do that... :( Edit: Got it. I clicked the tick! Sorry

Comment: Thanks @user3207501! :) Now the next step is getting yourself a nicer username ;)